# print python dictionary in particular style

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How to print a Python dictionary in this given pattern. I was asked this question in an interview and I couldn't solve it.

Input dictionary:

```
{"abc":{"def":{"ghi":{"jkl":{"mno":{"pqr":{"stu":{"vwx":{"yz":"you are finally here !!!"}}}}}}}}}
```

Desired output:

```
{"abc":["def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqr","stu","vwx","yz"],
 "def":["ghi","jkl","mno","pqr","stu","vwx","yz"],
 "ghi":["jkl","mno","pqr","stu","vwx","yz"],
 "jkl":["mno","pqr","stu","vwx","yz"],
 "mno":["pqr","stu","vwx","yz"],
 "pqr":["stu","vwx","yz"],
 "stu":["vwx","yz"],
 "vwx":["yz"],
 "yz":["you are finally here !!!"]}
```

Comment: Those dictionaries are not the same, so there's more than just pretty printing going on here.

Comment: This seems more a question about “could you turn this dict into this dict.” Extremely quick solution is to start a loop, get the first key, add to a list if the key’s value is a dict, and keep doing this with inner dicts until the value is not a dict. Assign that inner value to its own list. Now iterate over the list of keys, and for each item in the list, slice from the item position + 1 to the end to get all the sublist keys and add those to the final dict. I’m sure after you got there they probably would have asked about reducing memory usage or whatever.

Comment: @Blckknght it's considering first value as key and remaining keys as value

Comment: @j1-lee then how to get the solution.

Comment: Maybe you could improve the title and the description of your question? The actual problem is not about printing, but recursively accessing the keys of nested dictionaries and generating a new structure (list of keys(?)). Also, while "I have no idea how to solve it" is a valid description of the state of your research, you are supposed to have the basic intuition to, _at least_, say something like "I guess there must be a solution using a recursive function but couldn't figure it out".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick recursive solution:

```
from pprint import pprint

data = {"abc":{"def":{"ghi":{"jkl":{"mno":{"pqr":{"stu":{"vwx":{"yz":"you are finally here !!!"}}}}}}}}}

def a_particular_style(data):
    ret = {}
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            d = a_particular_style(v)
            ret.update(d)
            ret[k] = list(reversed(d))
        else:
            ret[k] = [v]
    return ret

pprint(a_particular_style(data))
```

```
{'abc': ['def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz'],
 'def': ['ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz'],
 'ghi': ['jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz'],
 'jkl': ['mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz'],
 'mno': ['pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz'],
 'pqr': ['stu', 'vwx', 'yz'],
 'stu': ['vwx', 'yz'],
 'vwx': ['yz'],
 'yz': ['you are finally here !!!']}
```

Since each "level" of the dict is built from the next level down, it's easier to visualize how this works if you start at the bottom with the smallest dict:

```
print(a_particular_style({"yz":"you are finally here !!!"}))
# {'yz': ['you are finally here !!!']}

print(a_particular_style({"vwx":{"yz":"you are finally here !!!"}}))
# {'vwx': ['yz'], 'yz': ['you are finally here !!!']}    

print(a_particular_style({"stu":{"vwx":{"yz":"you are finally here !!!"}}}))
# {'stu': ['vwx', 'yz'], 'vwx': ['yz'], 'yz': ['you are finally here !!!']}

# etc
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple 5 line solution using recursion like this should work:

```
>>> input_dict = {"abc":{"def":{"ghi":{"jkl":{"mno":{"pqr":{"stu":{"vwx":{"yz":"you are finally here !!!"}}}}}}}}}
>>> reshaper = lambda x, y=[]: (y, x) if type(x) == str else my_func(x[list(x)[0]], y+list(x))
>>> final_list = reshaper(input_dict)
>>> final_dict = {key: final_list[0][i+1:] for i, key in enumerate(final_list[0][:-1])}
>>> final_dict.update({final_list[0][-1]: final_list[1]})
>>> final_dict
{'abc': ['def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz'], 'def': ['ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz'], 'ghi': ['jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz'], 'jkl': ['mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz'], 'mno': ['pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz'], 'pqr': ['stu', 'vwx', 'yz'], 'stu': ['vwx', 'yz'], 'vwx': ['yz'], 'yz': 'you are finally here !!!'}
```

What this method, which I think may be one of the simplest solutions, does is it takes the dictionary and recurs through the dictionaries within dictionaries, appending each key to a list till we are left with the final string.

It then takes this list and iterates through the list to create a dictionary with values being slices with an index greater than the index of the key.

Answer (score -1):

```py
a = {"abc":{"def":{"ghi":{"jkl":{"mno":{"pqr":{"stu":{"vwx":{"yz":"you are finally here !!!"}}}}}}}}}

d = {}
loop = True
while loop:
    for i in a:
        if i == 'yz':
            loop = False
        d[i] = []
        a = a[i]

for i in d:
    pos = list(d.keys())
    d[i] = pos[pos.index(i) + 1:]
print(d)
```

Here is a bad solution . I somehow made it work, *almost*.
upvote if works!!

Comment: almost works != it works